# Synaptic & aptitude broken after upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: 15.10, 16.04, synaptic, aptitude

after I upgraded Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 (Wily Werewolf) to 16.04 (Xenial Xerus), I cannot start synaptic or aptitude for installing new software, and 'apt-get install whatever' does not work either. Here is the error I always get:

> The value 'wily is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release
>   is not available in the sources.

I read a lot about this error on Google etc., but the solutions proprosed on the web only work for older versions of Ubuntu or Debian. What I tried e.g. was checking the value of APT::Default-Release within `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, but it is not set there, it is not set in any text file within `/etc/apt/` or any of its subdirectories. I removed all files from the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, because these were related to older Ubuntu versions.

Anymore ideas?

P.S. 1: A bit more information about my environment:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

P.S. 2: Output from `sudo apt edit-sources` (removed commented lines):

```
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

deb http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

deb http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

deb http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

deb http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ xenial partner
```

Comment: Please check your version using 'lsb_release -a' and add the output to the above post. In addition run 'sudo apt edit-sources' (opens your sources in default editor) and paste the output as well.  For me it sounds like your apt sources do refer to wily sources instead of xenial

Comment: I would try to move '/root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf' to '/root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf.backup' and see if that helps. Assuming there are errors in synaptic.conf. If it doesnt helps - revert the change.

Comment: Did that too, but still doesn't work :-/.

Comment: Just 'sudo apt clean'?

Comment: Which server you are using to download programs? "System Settings" -> "Download from" section? Maybe selecting it to main server can be good.

Comment: @emk2203 That worked =). I did not assume that the solution would be so easy. If you post your comment as answer you'll get the +50 bounty reputation from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have problems with a "stuck" `apt` or the higher-level programs `aptitude` or `synaptic`, a cleaning of the apt cache may be necessary.

This is especially the case after a distribution update.

```
sudo apt clean
```

is quick and easy and helps with a lot of stuck apt systems. I do it routinely after a lot of updates have been made, or after a dist-upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Open `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01ubuntu` using `nano`, like

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01ubuntu
```

Then , type the following as it is:

```
APT::Default-Release "xenial";
```

Clean your `apt` cache by running:

```
sudo rm -rfv /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Then create the the `partial` folder which was removed by the previous command:

```
sudo mkdir -pv /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
```

To make sure, that you have cleaned your lists, run the following command:

```
sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoclean
```

Now, update your repository information:

```
sudo apt update --fix-missing
```

This should fix your errors.

Comment: Well, your answer looks quite elaborated, but the other guy's been first, sorry.

Comment: I did upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04 but I can't find /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01ubuntu on my machine. should I create it ?

Comment: @Cristiano Yes, you can manually create the file. Apt will automatically load the settings of the file.

Comment: thanks @AbhimanyuSaharan, but unfortunately I'm still getting the annoying message:"The value 'trusty-proposed' is invalid for APT::Default-Release...". Do you know where this value is set ? I'm running xenial.

Comment: @Cristiano Try running grep command to search for the file. `grep trusty-proposed /etc/apt/*` I have not tested this command but see if it helps you

Comment: @AbhimanyuSaharan, I found the file containing the wrong sentence here: /root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf
After change it, synaptic started properly. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

that mirror was broken untill earlier this morning , see the date and time on the Xenial folders. It should work now.

```
http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu/dists/
```

Its best to use the standard redirector for your country instead as it would not have included a broken mirror.

```
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```